# Drupal 8 rewrite a hook

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to rewrite a hook `comment_node_links_alter`. How can I do it? I created a file `THEME.theme` in my theme, placed there `THEME_comment_node_links_alter` but it is not called. I cannot find any distinct information how to rewrite hooks. I observed `bartik.theme` and saw that all hooks are prepended with a theme name. I did the same. Did clear the cache. My funciton is included, I checked with xdebug. But it is never called.

Comment: Why you want to rewrite the hook? Or you want to use another template for the block?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I want to remove comment link from teaser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused about how Drupal hooks work. You don't overwrite the existing function you instead create your own function that is called when the relevant part of the site is loaded. (So in this case node links)

So there is no THEME_comment_node_links_alter hook. There is HOOK_node_links_alter. So I'm guessing you looked in the comment module and saw comment_node_links_alter which is actually the comment module implementing HOOK_node_links_alter

In your theme/module you'd want to replicate what the comment module is doing so something like

```
THEME_node_links_alter(
```

With THEME being your theme machine name. THen that will mean your function is called and you can amend the variables

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_links_alter/8.4.x

Comment: I got now. But strange, the hook is not called. I named it `THEME_node_links_alter`. But no results. I created `kapusta_preprocess_menu` for test. It works. And I checked everything several times.

Comment: I also tried to add `bartik_node_links_alter` to bartik theme. It is also not called.

Comment: I would  imagine this would have to be done in a .module file and not a theme. And also you'd need to flush all site changes after adding the code so drupal knows your module is now using this hook

Comment: module works. But the question is still open: how to do the same in .theme.

Comment: You don't. Themes can't implement hooks except in a few specific cases.

Comment: @Berdir what are these cases? Is this info in docs? I can see a lot of hooks in `bartik.theme`.

Comment: Yes, what bartik is doing is almost the full list. form alters, preprocess and theme suggestions. By default, themes are not invoked by hooks anymore in D8 except if explicitly implemented. One reason is that many hooks are cached, and it could lead to completely unpredictable results depending on which theme was active when the cache was built.